# Convert to 4 2-input NAND Gates

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I need to express $(\bar A + \bar B)(A + B)$ using only 4 2-input NAND gates.

The hint given is: distribute the content in the second parentheses and then do De' Morgan's Law three times)

All I can think that means is: $$(\bar A + \bar B)(A + B)(A + B)$$

Applying De' Morgan's: $$(\overline{AB}) \overline{(\bar A \bar B)} \overline{(\bar A \bar B)}$$

There should be three top bars but I can't figure out how not to combine the last two... Is it the same thing regardless?

Is this even correct? Where can I go from here?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43342/how-to-construct-xor-gate-using-only-4-nand-gate) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just in case it helps anyone else. I was just dumb...

Go from: $(\bar A + \bar B)(A + B)$

To: $A(\bar A + \bar B) + B(\bar A + \bar B)$

Use De' Morgans a couple times and you're good!